# Export and import functions in java

Tags: java, mockito

In mockito, we can import Mockito class and use it function like `any()` or `when()`.

Is it possible to import only the functions that I need from my class?

Comment: if it is static method you can import static method only other wise you have to import all class

Comment: You can use `import static`, as stated in the answer.  But the wording of your question ("import only the functions") makes it sound like you want to avoid importing other functions.  If that's what you're trying to accomplish--why?  I'm asking this in case you have a misunderstanding about how things work in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you, the answer is Yes. You need only `import` those Mockito functions that you want to use. For example, if you only want to use `when()`, then that's the only function you need to import. Here's how you do so:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
```